# How to change the commit cvs comment after commit in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I commited the code in CVS using eclipse, by mistake i wrote the wrong comments and committed the code. Now i want to change the comment, is it possible?

If so please let me know how to change it?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the comment with the cvs command line tool:

```
cvs admin -m $version:"$newcomment" $filename
```

If your comment has multiple lines:

```
cvs admin -m $version:"`cat /path/to/comment_file.txt`" $filename
```

Comment: Cant we do from eclipse?